# Не срабатывают Routes, Route, Navigate с пакета react-router-dom

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router-dom, route, router

Работаю с нодой не так давно и не знаю всех тонкостей. Методом пробы и вывода понял что не выводит данные написанные в тегах Routes, Route, Navigate которые импортирую с пакета react-router-dom. Подскажите, как можно это решить?

```
import React from 'react';
import {Routes, Route, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import {LinksPage} from './pages/LinksPage';
import {CreatePage} from './pages/CreatePage';
import {DetailPage} from './pages/DetailPage';
import {AuthPage} from './pages/AuthPage';
 
export const useRoutes = isAuthenticated => {
    if (isAuthenticated){
        return(
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/links" element={<LinksPage />}></Route>
                <Route path="/create"  element={<CreatePage />}></Route>
                <Route path="/detail/:id"  element={<DetailPage />}></Route>
                <Navigate to="/create"/>
            </Routes>
        )
    }
 
    return(
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<AuthPage />}></Route>
            <Navigate to="/" />
        </Routes>
    )
}
```

Comment: Вот и я не понимаю что именно вы хотите? Единственное чем могу сейчас помочь это дать ссылку на свой рабочий пример работы с Router https://codepen.io/latdev/pen/poPVgPg . А вообще стоило-бы уточнить суть вопроса. А ещё было-бы неплохо уточнить версию React и React Router, потому что в последних версиях они кое-что поменяли в Router'е

Comment: @EugeneX зачем так агрессивно то? Человек не понимает и хочет помощи. Написал же не так давно работает с нодой.  Скорее всего `BrowserRouter` не добавил к корню.